# Angular CLI fails on downloading Angular 6 dependencies thru proxy behind

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I've successfully installed Angular CLI using NPM behind proxy with Fiddler.

But now I'm facing problem when using 'ng new' command of Angular CLI.

It Always fails to download some dependencies that gives me E502 error.

here is the configuration I used for NPM:

```
npm config set proxy=http://myproxyserveraddress:8888/
npm config set https-proxy=http://username:password@myproxyserveraddress:8888/
npm config set strict-ssl=false
npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

for fiddler, I put check on the Auto Authenticate on the Rules menu.

I also tried the other NPM configurations that was posted here but no luck and those instructions looks outdated now.

Is there an updated configuration setting for creating new project in Angular CLI thru proxy behind?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@myproxyserveraddress:8888/
```

I think you need set the usn and password in both http and http. And, the character between "proxy" and "http" is a "space" not "=" . Or you can check the username. Ex: my usn in company is xxxx\xxxxxx